# Turn an element's CSS on/off using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlighting

I currently have the following block of HTML that I am using to highlight a particular area of a .png file:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://www.placekitten.com/200/200" />
    <div id="highlight"></div>
</div>
```

its corresponding CSS code looks like this:

```
#container {
    positioon:relative;
}
#highlight {
    position:absolute;
    width:75px;
    height:75px;
    top:75px;
    left:75px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Both can be seen working together on the following [page](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cbESu/).

The code works fine, but what I would like to do is figure out a way to turn the highlighting on/off by having a JavaScript function in control of this feature.  I am a JavaScript novice, and not sure how to approach this.  All I want is to be able to pass a variable to a JavaScript function, and based on this boolean variable, either activate, or deactivate the shading.

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: Instead of setting the style by `id`, set it by `class`, and add/remove the class when you want the highlighting to be on/off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function toggleHighlight(on)
{
  var el = document.getElementById('highlight');

  el.style['display'] = on ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

called as:

```
toggleHighlight(true);  // turn on
toggleHighlight(false); // turn off
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CSS class rule:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And with javascript add or remove that class to the elements you want to toggle. This way when an element has `class="none"` it won't be shown, and just by removing `class="none"` it will show up again.

Here there is a good question about adding and removing classes with pure javascript: [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you said, you want that when someone goes with pointer through a div, show or hide it.

If I'm not wrong, you only have to use `#highlight:hover {...}` and no javascript is needed.

Also, you have to add `display: block` property and by default it has to be `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Fiddle I can see you use jquery, so this can be achieved using this code:

```
// show the element
$('#highlight').hide();
// hide the element
$('#highlight').show();
```

I've [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/cbESu/1/) your example to test the hide function.